# C, timer_settime, disarm timer and overwrite associated data?

Tags: c, timer, signals, real-time, handler

I have to do for University a project about UDP, where i have to guarantee reliable communication; for packets, i want use timer_gettime() and timer_Settime() functions, because i can queue signals and i can associate to them a timer; in particular, struct sigevent has a field which union sigval where i can pass value to handler when signal arrived; I would like to take advantage of this passing to handler number of packets for which timer expired; I have a problem, and I've done a simple program to verify this; when I start timer, i can disarm it setting it_value of struct sigevent to 0; but data doesn't change; if I send 100 signal, header receives only data of first signal. This is my code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int d;


void err_exit(char* str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


void sighandler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    (void) sig;
    (void) uc;
    d = si->si_value.sival_int;
}



void handle_signal(struct sigaction* sa)
{
    sa->sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa->sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa->sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(SIGRTMAX,sa,NULL) == -1)
        err_exit("sigaction");
}



void create_timer(struct sigevent* sev,timer_t* timer_id,int i)
{
    union sigval s;
    s.sival_int = i;
    printf("value: %d\n",i);
    sev->sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev->sigev_signo = SIGRTMAX;
    sev->sigev_value = s;


    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,sev,timer_id);

}


void set_timer(timer_t timer_id,struct itimerspec* ts)
{
    if(ts == NULL)
        printf("itimerspec null\n");
    if (timer_settime(timer_id, 0, ts, NULL) == -1){
        printf("errno code: %d\n",errno);
        err_exit("timer_settime");
    }
}



void initialize_timerspec(struct itimerspec* ts)
{
    ts->it_value.tv_sec = 2;
    ts->it_value.tv_nsec = 5;
    ts->it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    ts->it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
}



void reset_timer(timer_t timer_id, struct itimerspec* ts)
{
    ts->it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    ts->it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    ts->it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    ts->it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    if (timer_settime(timer_id, 0, ts, NULL) == -1){
            printf("errno code: %d\n",errno);
            err_exit("timer_settime");
    }
}





int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct itimerspec ts[2];
    struct sigevent sev[2];
    timer_t timer_id[2];

    handle_signal(&sa);


    create_timer(sev,timer_id,0);
    initialize_timerspec(ts);
    set_timer(timer_id,ts);
    reset_timer(timer_id,ts);


    create_timer(sev + 1,timer_id + 1,1);
    initialize_timerspec(ts + 1);
    set_timer(timer_id,ts + 1);

    printf("id1: %ju    id2:  %ju\n",timer_id[0],timer_id[1]);
    sleep(10);

    printf("d = %d\n",d);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I disarm first timer, and send another signal; but handler receives data associated to first signal, because it prints 0. Is there a way to send to overwrite data, sending to handler data of second signal(in this case 1)?

Comment: Can you please let the forum know the platform you are using?

Comment: Sorry for my ingorance, what do you mean?IDE that i'm using?